# PHP - Contact form not sending data

Tags: php, html, contact-form

I am working on a website that has a simple contact form in which the website visitor can enter his name, E-mail address and his message and all of those data will be sent to a destination E-mail, I tried several solutions but I can't find the result in the destination E-mail.

**PS:** I have my HTTP SERVER up and running using EasyPhp

**HTML SOURCE**

```
<form method="post" action="C:\Users\myPC\Desktop\WEBSITE\root\assets\php\contact.php">
     <div>
          <label for="name">Name: </label>
          <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
     </div>
     <div>
          <label for="email">Email: </label>
          <input type="email" id="email" name="email">
     </div>
     <div>
          <label for="message">Message: </label>
          <textarea id="message" name="message" rows="4"></textarea>
     </div>
     <button type="submit" name="send">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**PHP SOURCE**

```
<?php 
      $name = $_POST['name']; //user input name
      $email = $_POST['email']; //user input email
      $message = $_POST['message']; //user input message

      $secured_name = htmlspecialchars($name);
      $secured_email = htmlspecialchars($email);
      $secured_message; = htmlspecialchars($message);

      $formcontent="From: $secured_name \n Message: $secured_message"; //E-mail body (username + e-mail message)
      $recipient = "myservice@outlook.com"; //support service EMAIL
      $subject = "Contact request - website"; //E-mail subject
      $mailheader = "From: $secured_email \r\n"; //sender E-mail

      //action
      if (isset($_POST["send"])) {
         mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) 
         or die("Error!");
      }
?>
```

Comment: What does your `onclick="submitForm()"` do?  Also how does the PHP function `submitForm()` get called?

Comment: Your action should be an url and not a local path.

Comment: I was trying out several methods @NigelRen

Comment: Are you sure action path is good ? Seems weird to me

Comment: onclick="submitForm() is a javascript event handler, your action is in the PHP file... Use one or the other.

Comment: as for the `onclick()` event I updated the code

Comment: Windows use SMTP instead of `sendmail` bin on Linux. Change SMTP info in your `php.ini`, then restart your Apache to see if it works. However, you should use a mail lib (phpmailer, swiftmailer, etc)

Comment: Now just use something like: if(isset($_POST['send'])... in your PHP action file and then process the data

Comment: change your form's action to a url relative to your html source's location. like `action="assets/php/contact.php"`